# Setting the http.nonProxyHosts programmatically in Android

Tags: android, cordova, nanohttpd

So I have an embedded server (nanohttpd) running in my cordova-based android application and instead of pointing my webview to file://....index.html, I have it pointed to load the index.html from my local webserver (http://localhost:8000/index.html). This works fine, however, when my Wi-Fi connection has a configured proxy, then it fails to load unless I manually add localhost to the "Bypass Proxy for" field in the proxy settings. Now my question is, is it possible to do this programmatically?

I've tried calling System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost") and invoking PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION intent through Reflections but it didn't work. I need my app to run on Kitkat and above.

Thanks!